# How to work around rank N polymorphism in C#?

Tags: c#, type-systems, rank-n-types

Suppose there is an identity function, which is:

```
T Id<T>(T t) { return t; }
```

What should I type `F`?

```
void F<T>(Func<T, T> f) { // This is not sound!
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", f(1));
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", f("one"));
}

static void Main() {
    F(Id);
}
```

I think C# doesn't have rank N polymorphism and C# cannot type `F` soundly. Is this right?

And then how to work around such issues?

Comment: You're going to need to elaborate, a lot. It's true that the code you posted won't work. But why would you want it to work? Your "generic" method only uses `T` for the sake of invoking the `f` delegate. You could just as easily declare the method `void F(Func<object, object> f) { ... }` and it would work.

Comment: `void F(Func<object, object> f) { ... }` is not type-safe. If  `F` has such type, `f` can be `string Foo(int v) { return v + ""; }`.

Comment: This seems on the face of it to be an academic question about a feature that the C# language doesn't support.  Can you give an actual use case?

Comment: I am trying to transform Sprache (parser combinator library) into CPS'd with referencing attoparsec (parser combinator in Haskell).

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve, but you could do this with a non-generic interface that contains a generic method:

```
using System;

interface IGenericSameTypeFunction
{
    T Apply<T>(T input);
}

public class SimpleIdentityFunction : IGenericSameTypeFunction
{
    public T Apply<T>(T input) => input;
}

class Test
{    
    static void F(IGenericSameTypeFunction function)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(function.Apply(1));
        Console.WriteLine(function.Apply("one"));
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        F(new SimpleIdentityFunction());
    }
}
```

The important aspect is that by making the `Apply` method generic rather than the `F` method, you're saying "This is a function that can be applied in a type-safe way to any type."

There's no way of expressing that interface as a delegate type though.